# Poincaré theorem about the unit ball and the unit polydisc

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

In Rudin's book "Function theory in the unit ball of $\mathbb{C}^n$", it is proven that the open unit ball $\mathbb{B}^n$ and the open unit polydisc $\Delta^n$ are not biholomorphically equivalent, because otherwise there would be a linear biholomorphism between them, and invertible linear transformations map balls onto ellipsoids.

Now, my question is whether there is a simple way to show that a cartesian product of discs cannot be the image of the unit ball by means of an invertible linear transformation. In particular, I am looking for something that does not involve the fact that the ball has a smooth boundary, while the polydisc does not. The whole point of Rudin's proof is to use only linear maps.

Comment: Is it OK to think in terms of convexity theory? The unit ball is strictly convex (i.e., the interior of the line segment joining any two of its points is contained in its interior). The product of two or more discs is not strictly convexity. Strict convexity is preserved under invertible linear transformations.

Comment: Oh really, the boundary of a polydisc is not smooth? This is surprising to me, are you sure about that? Sorry if this does not help you at all

Comment: Answering to @RobArthan: this would answer my question if this was true. However, it does not seem to be the case. Just take $\Delta^n=\{z=(z_1, \dots, z_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n : |z_j|<1, j=1,\dots, n\}$. Then, take $t\in [0,1]$ and $z,w\in\Delta^n$. For every $j$, one has $|tz_j+(1-t)w_j|\leq t|z_j|+(1-t)|w_j|<t+(1-t)=1$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Answering to @GiuseppeNegro: Yes, I am pretty sure about that. Can you prove me wrong?

Comment: I am not implying that you are wrong or anything, just that I find it surprising. But actually it is not that surprising, now that I think about it, since the product of two intervals is a square, which is not smooth. I learned something. Your question is interesting.

Comment: Rob’s suggestion looks sound to me. The disc is strictly convex. The square is not. This must generalise to arbitrary dimension somewhat... The concept of [extremal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein–Milman_theorem) seems to be relevant here.

Comment: Answering to @GiuseppeNegro: Scusami, il tono astioso non era nelle mie intenzioni! By the way, I did some research, and I must conclude that this is actually true and quite obvious, but very boring to prove rigorously. Just check this, on page 5: https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1990-22-02/S0273-0979-1990-15879-3/S0273-0979-1990-15879-3.pdf

Comment: Your comments suggest me another way to pose my question: given a linear bijection between the open ball and the open polydisc, does it also map bijectively the boundary of the ball onto the boundary of the polydisk? Maybe this would give me the contradiction I seek.

Comment: @Riccardo On page 237 of the article that you have linked in your second last comment the author claims that there is no linear biholomorphism between the sets $\{(z,w) : |z|^2+|w|^2<1\}$ and $\{(z,w):|z|^4+|w|^2<1\}$ without stating any argument for it. Do you know the argument for it? Why there cannot be any linear biholomorphism between these sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like I have found a satisfactory answer. As Rob and Giuseppe suggested, it involves convexity. The proof I give is taken from Kaup's book "Holomorphic functions of several variables", page 10.

If $F:\mathbb{B}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{\Delta}^n$ is a linear bijection, then it is defined on all of $\mathbb{C}^n$, hence $F(\partial\mathbb{B}^n)=\partial\Delta^n$ (this follows in fact from a quite elementary argument). But $\partial\Delta^n$ includes the real segment $\{(1,t,0, \dots,0):t\in[-1,1]\}$. Since $F^{-1}$ is linear, $\partial\mathbb{B}^n=F^{-1}(\partial\Delta^n)$ must contain a real segment as well, which is clearly impossible.

Thanks for all the kind suggestions!

Comment: Why can we restrict to linear transformations?

Comment: This follows from one of Cartan's uniqueness theorems, which states that a biholomorphic map $F:\Omega_1\rightarrow\Omega_2$ with $F(0)=0$ is linear, provided that $\Omega_1$ is bounded and $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are circular domains containing $0$. Now, since the group of automorphisms of the unit ball acts transitively on the ball, one can assume without loss of generality that a biholomorphism from the ball to the unit polydisk fixes the origin, hence it is linear. For more details, see Chapter 2 of Rudin's "Function theory in the unit ball of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Circular domains ?

Comment: A connected open set $\Omega$ such that for every $z\in\Omega$ and every $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $e^{i\theta}z\in\Omega$.